# getting and setting global co-ordinates of component in Flex AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Hi all
   I've some components in container, these components are drag-able in order to be drop at their target. But if they are being dragged away from their target then they should be replaced at their original position.
 Problem is that when I get x and y co ordinates at the mouse down event, and set that co ordinates on on mouse up event, but it is not going to its original position because x and y are its local co ordinates in container.

I want to ask how to get global co ordinates and then set at other time, so that it will come to their original position. Can some one give me piece of code?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Downvoting this post because you appear to have abandoned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flex the MouseEvent class has a stageX and stageY property in addition to localX and localY. The stage properties represent the global position of the event.

I'm sure you can store these recall them later to reposition the component.

see: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#stageX